# Triggering an Action from a UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know a good method to look at for getting a search bar to trigger an action when the user touches it? i am trying to create a search bar that when touched triggers a new search View controller to get pushed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method would be to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` Protocol in your view controller. Then, implement `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` in the delegate, and display your view inside of that method.